# Lubuntu: Open as root not working in pcmanfm-qt

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm-qt

I have an almost fresh install of Lubuntu 20.04 and pcmanfm-qts "Open as root" function in the tools menu is not working. I can choose it, enter my password and then simply nothing happens.

I've also gone through the bug reports on github regarding similar issues like [this](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/958). The conclusion is that I have `lxqt-sudo %s` in the "switch user command" setting and changing it to recommendations in these but report does not solve the problem, like `lxsudo dbus-run-session -- %s`. same behavior. I get the password prompt and then nothing happens.

If I enter the command into cli, for example:

```
lxqt-sudo /usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt /etc
```

I get the password prompt and then below error:

> No protocol specified
> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :10.0
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling   the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

And then the command exists. I have a Lubuntu 20.04 VM in which this works flawlessly. Hence my only explanation for the issue is that I'm trying to do this through xrdp.

Any idea what could cause this issue and how to solve it?